# Error: Nothing to repeat at offset error during a preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to find if a file name contains some special characters I don't want.

I'm using this code actually:

```
$files = array("logo.png", "légo.png");
$badChars = array(" ", "é", "É", "è", "È", "à", "À", "ç", "Ç", "¨", "^", "=", "/", "*", "-", "+", "'", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "`", "~", "/", "", "|", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "?", "&", "(", ")", "¬", "{", "}", "[", "]", "ù", "Ù", '"', "«", "»");
$matches = array();

foreach($files as $file) {
    $matchFound = preg_match_all("#\b(" . implode("|", $badChars) . ")\b#i", $file, $matches);
}
if ($matchFound) {
    $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $results[] = array('Error' => "Forbided chars found : ". $word);
    }
}
else {
    $results[] = array('Success' => "OK.");
}
```

But I have an error saying:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 38 in /home/public_html/upload.php on line 138
```

Which is:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all("#\b(" . implode("|", $badChars) . ")\b#i", $file, $matches);
```

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because `?` `*` `+` are quantifiers. Since they are not escaped you obtain this error: `|?` there is obviously nothing to repeat.

For your task you don't need to use an alternation, a character class should suffice:

```
if (preg_match_all('~[] éèàç¨^=/*-+\'<>:;,`\~/|!@#$%?&()¬{}[ù"«»]~ui', $file, $m)) {
    $m = array_unique($m[0]);
    $m = array_map(function ($i) use ($file) { return array('Error' => 'Forbidden character found : ' . $i . ' in ' . $file); }, $m);
    $results = array_merge($results, $m);
}
```

or perhaps this pattern: `~[^[:alnum:]]~`

Comment: Got a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','` for your first line.

Comment: The answer has changed, refresh your browser.

Comment: Looks good but I've got this `Forbided chars found : Array` whereas I would like `Forbided chars found : +` for example. How can I change it?

Comment: Can I use the `$file` name ? Just to say `Forbidden chars found in the $file`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your characters have `*` in it, which tries to repeat the previous character, which in your case ends up being `|`, which is invalid. Your regex turns into:

```
..... |/|*|-| .....
```

Map [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to your character array before your loop and you'll be fine:

```
$badChars = array_map( 'preg_quote', $badChars);
```

Just make sure that since you're not specifying your delimiter `#` in the call to `preg_quote()`, you'll have to manually escape it in your `$badChars` array.